# Error when trying to update IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1.1 and I'm trying to update to 2021.1.1.3 (last available so far).

I'm trying by Help > Check for Updates > Update > Update and Restarts

Nothing Happens...

In the log file have this error:

> 2021-10-29 12:10:24,884 [268243632]  ERROR -
> llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - class
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl cannot be cast to
> class com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginNode
> (com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl and
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginNode are in unnamed module of loader
> com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader @67b6d4ae)
> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl cannot be cast to
> class com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginNode
> (com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl and
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginNode are in unnamed module of loader
> com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader @67b6d4ae)     at
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.newui.ListPluginComponent.createTag(ListPluginComponent.java:293)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.newui.ListPluginComponent.(ListPluginComponent.java:105)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginUpdateDialog.createListComponent(PluginUpdateDialog.java:255)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginUpdateDialog.lambda$new$2(PluginUpdateDialog.java:115)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.newui.PluginsGroupComponent.addToGroup(PluginsGroupComponent.java:200)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.newui.PluginsGroupComponent.addGroup(PluginsGroupComponent.java:182)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.newui.PluginsGroupComponent.addGroup(PluginsGroupComponent.java:73)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.newui.PluginsGroupComponent.addGroup(PluginsGroupComponent.java:69)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginUpdateDialog.(PluginUpdateDialog.java:127)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.PluginUpdateDialog.(PluginUpdateDialog.java:71)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.UpdateInfoDialog.downloadPatchAndRestart(UpdateInfoDialog.java:218)
> ...

Comment: Please install the current version manually from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html. The issue is not clear from this log fragment. You may want to report it at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the complete logs attached via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data. 2021.1.1.3 is not the current IntelliJ IDEA version.

Answer (score 0):

I also have your issue,you can not try by Help > Check for Updates > Update > Update and Restarts,but Files > settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates,then check for updates,ok

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to work around it by installing the update via the Jetbrains toolbox app. You can find it here : https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/